# Windows CMD Scripting: Why SET don't work inside parentheses?

Tags: windows, command-line, script

Actually I want to redirect output to file like

```
@echo off
(
  set res=fail
  echo %res%
) > out.log
```

And redirection itself works fine... But why %res% is empty inside the parentheses?

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem This does not affect/help here

(
  setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  rem This does not affect/help here too

  set res=fail
  echo %res%  
  rem res is empty here
)
echo %res%    
rem res=fail here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 Issues here:

(1) You should execute it inside a batch script , not at command-line.

(2) You should use `EXCLAMATION !` ( not `PERCENT %` ) with `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`.

Here is a working Case , which you can put in BT.BAT to check.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO UNABLE TO ENABLE EXTENSIONS

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO UNABLE TO ENABLE DELAYED EXPANSION

SET res=UNfail
ECHO OFF

ECHO OUTSIDE 1 WITH PERCENT : %res%
ECHO OUTSIDE 1 WITH EXCLAMATION : !res!

(
  SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
  SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
  SET res=fail

  ECHO INSIDE 1 WITH PERCENT : %res%
  ECHO INSIDE 1 WITH EXCLAMATION : !res!
)

ECHO OUTSIDE 2 WITH PERCENT : %res%
ECHO OUTSIDE 2 WITH EXCLAMATION : !res!

(
  SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
  SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
  SET res=failUN

  ECHO INSIDE 2 WITH PERCENT : %res%
  ECHO INSIDE 2 WITH EXCLAMATION : !res!
)

ECHO OUTSIDE 3 WITH PERCENT : %res%
ECHO OUTSIDE 3 WITH EXCLAMATION : !res!
```

OUTPUT :

```
OUTSIDE 1 WITH PERCENT : UNfail
OUTSIDE 1 WITH EXCLAMATION : UNfail
INSIDE 1 WITH PERCENT : UNfail
INSIDE 1 WITH EXCLAMATION : fail
OUTSIDE 2 WITH PERCENT : fail
OUTSIDE 2 WITH EXCLAMATION : fail
INSIDE 2 WITH PERCENT : fail
INSIDE 2 WITH EXCLAMATION : failUN
OUTSIDE 3 WITH PERCENT : failUN
OUTSIDE 3 WITH EXCLAMATION : failUN
```